# Azure Web App (.NET) connecting to Oracle Database without installing client

Tags: .net, oracle, azure

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database from my Azure .NET web app.  The objective is to not have to install the Oracle client on the Azure Web App.

I've tried the few options out there but nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions?

Currently I'm receiving the following error:

> System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7
>   or greater.

Comment: Instead of 'connecting', what about implementing a REST API for your database? Then your web app can stay Web and do GET, PUT, POST, DELETE via HTTPS instead.

Comment: I would love/prefer that option.  Unfortunately, my task is to "lift & shift" from on-prem to Azure.

In fact, I am leveraging Hybrid Connectors for SQL Server and Oracle.  The dbs will remain on-prem until a later date.

Comment: Maybe you could check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/02/23/access-oracle-databases-from-azure-web-apps-using-oci8-drivers-with-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According error messages it seems that you use the `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace. This is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) for ages, you should not use it.

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html) the ODP.NET Managed Driver. You just have to copy a single DLL, no further installation is required for that.

Comment: You are correct.  I inherited this code and was trying to use what was there.  Ultimately, I re-designed/coded the database classes to use the latest Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package - which means I had to do NOTHING :) That package makes it so easy.

For others who might be looking...

Instead of the deprecated System.Data.OracleClient namespace, the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.