# Connecting to Oracle Database from Azure PHP8 web application?

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, oci8

I have Azure web app in PHP8 and want connect to Oracle database 12C from php code. From documentation, I found below blog it says that we need to have Oracle Instant Client but I am not finding the steps to install. And in this blog they mentioned php version upto 5.6 but I am using PHP 8 version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/access-oracle-databases-from-azure-web-apps-using-oci8-drivers-with-php

Any leads on this to install Oracle instant client?

Comment: Check related questions on Stackoverflow.  If you still have problems, then update your question with technical details about what you have installed and the outcome

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we can not install oracle instant client on Azure Web App. Need to leverage  the **Azure VM** to install oracle client.

As [Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones) mentioned Please refer the below links for related issues:

. [Web App with Oracle Instant Client | MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ae324670-cd0f-4be5-a382-31e443129420/web-app-with-oracle-instant-client?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

.[Azure Web App, PHP 7.4, OCI8 (Oracle Instant Client 12.2.0.1.0)| SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534412/azure-web-app-php-7-4-oci8-oracle-instant-client-12-2-0-1-0)

. [Enable PHP Extension (php_odbc.dll) on Azure | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795602/enable-php-extension-php-odbc-dll-on-azure/59822450#59822450).

. [Does Azure PHP 7 web app have Oracle drivers| SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970166/does-azure-php-7-web-app-have-oracle-drivers) .

. [Azure Web App (.NET) connecting to Oracle Database without installing client | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571347/azure-web-app-net-connecting-to-oracle-database-without-installing-client) .